# Monitoring system temperatures

Tags: 11.10, indicator, system, temperature, sensors

I would like to know if there's an indicator app that can show the system temperatures (CPU, MB, HDD, etc.).
I do have lm-sensors and hddtemp installed so that's no problem, I just need to find a good indicator app.

Does anyone know any good one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like System Monitor Indicator, but there are several of them. Have a look at the Ask Ubuntu community wiki on application indicators [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available). You might prefer System Load Indicator or Hardware Sensors Indicator.

Comment: Thanks. I've ended up using the Hardware Sensors Indicator.

Answer (score 1):

May be interested in installing Conky, and well-configured script?
You'll have everything on your desktop, or on The main bar at the Gnome 2.x without Unity.

Comment: I don't really like Conky. I prefer a clean desktop. Thanks for the suggestion though!